# How to send a message from one shell script to another shell script when both are running?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ipc

I have 3 shell scripts running in the background. Shell script 1 prints a message "Hello 1". The shell scripts 2 and 3 are also running in the background. I give the kill command to shell script 1. Now I use pgrep command in shell script 2 to know that script 1 is not running.

How can I notify this to script 3 from script 2 while both of them are already running in the background ? Once script 2 notifies script 3 then it should start printing "Hello 3". This is the entire task which I have to do.

Comment: Google "named pipe"

Comment: easiest solution is going to be a flat file or named pipe, though for either of these you'll also want to look at how to address concurrency issues (eg, research `flock`); if you have a (RDBMS) database available for (easy) use you could utilize the RDBMS's builtin lock management to serialize reads/writes on a 'shared' table/row; getting more complicated ... consider using a queuing system ... and then there's shared memory (though at this point you're likely talking about specialized (compiled) programming)

Comment: I'm a complete beginner. All these terms you said are new to me.

Comment: interprocess communication isn't exactly a 'beginner' topic sooooo ... how did you come up with this particular task/exercise? is this a homework assignment?

Comment: SO isn't the right place to be looking for (classroom like) instruction on interprocess communications; a google search on `interprocess communications` brings up quite a few hits (like this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) that can serve as a starting point for learning about said topic

Comment: I suggest to [edit] your question and explain what your system of shell scripts is supposed to do, how the scripts are started and what's the task of each script.

Answer (score 1):

Signals are one of the oldest inter-process communication methods used by Unix /Linux systems. They are used to signal asynchronous events to one or more processes.

You can send a signal to `script3` from `script2` when `pgrep` detects the condition you are looking for.

Take a look at

`help kill`

and

`help trap`